# how to read text documents with python 3.4

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to open a text document. I get the error `TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)` 
here is my code

```
doc=open("bradley.txt","r","UTF-8")
doc.read(5)
print(doc.read(5))
```

Comment: suggestion: skip the "r", it's the default

Comment: I have tried that but now I get  that the directory or path does not exist yet it exists..what do I do?

Comment: that will be a good SO question though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

open as

```
doc=open("bradley.txt","r",encoding="UTF-8")
```

docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html?highlight=open#io.open